# Removi a barra de ferramentas do atom, como coloca de volta?

Tags: editor-de-texto, atom

Acabei removendo sem querer a barra de ferramentas do Atom, aquela que fica em cima e que tem documentos, editar, etc...

Não sei como coloca de volta, alguém me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você provavelmente configurou para aparecer somente quando pressionar a tecla <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

Pressione a tecla <kbd>Alt</kbd>, quando o menu aparecer clique em `View > Toggle Menu Bar`.

Comment: Aeeeee, deu certo, kkkkkkkk é isso msm, vlw é nóis